# measure on matching ID and DATE in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, matching

I am trying to measure the average of a column based on a matching ID and DATE.

Example of tables:

[image]

So for example:
If in Table 2 the Date and ID matches the Date and ID of Table 1, I want the total average of the matching ID's in Table 1 with the ID's in Table 2.

Hope I described it clearly,
QW

Answer (score 0):

This is the data I have

[image]

Then I create new column, it is calculate column with below expression

```
ShouldbeAveraged= 
VAR Test =
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            Table2;
            Table1[Id] = Table2[Id]
                && Table1[Date Entered].[Date] = Table2[Date Entered].[Date]
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( Test = 1;"Yes";"No" )
```

The above expression will give you yes and no column whethere avg should be summed or not as below

[image]

and at last you create measure based on your new column as below

```
Total Avg = 
CALCULATE ( [Sum Avg];Table1[ShouldbeSummed]  = "Yes" )
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me the same outcome as: Planned Reistijd = calculate([Dag Reistijd]; FILTER(table1; table1[ID]); filter(table2; table2[ID])) It calculates the average of all the ID's in the Table. So when: the value ID "1"  in Table 2 matches the Date and ID in Table 1 I need the average of all the ID "1" in Table1.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple: Intersect

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE(
AVERAGE(AVG);
INTERSECT(
ALL(
Table1[ID]);
VALUES(Table2[ID])))
```

(: